# Angular pagination - update data onclick

Tags: angularjs, paging

I'm attempting to implement pagination on a angular/bootstrap site. I have the data showing with the correct # of per-page rows, I have the angular paging showing the right number of pages...but heck if I can find anywhere that tells me HOW to use the paging to refresh my data when a page # is clicked...?! {{currentPage}} is updating, but not sure how to have it call getPresentations to update the list.

```
<div>
        {{noOfPages}} &nbsp; {{currentPage}} &nbsp; {{maxSize}}
        <pagination num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage"></pagination>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', ['ui', 'shared', 'ui.bootstrap']).controller('AppCtl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
        var mvc = $window.MVC;
        $scope.noOfPages = 0;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.getPresentations = function () {
            $http.get(mvc.base + "API/Presentations?page=" + $scope.currentPage + "&itemsPerPage=10")
               .success(function (result) {
                   $scope.presentations = result.Items;
                   $scope.noOfPages = result.TotalPages;
                   $scope.currentPage = result.Page;
               })
                .error(function (result, status) {
                    $scope.newModal.errors = mvc.getApiErrors(status, result);
                });
        };

        $scope.getPresentations();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You've got 2 options:

- `$watch` the current-page property
- use the `onSelectPage` callback

Here is the relevant page with `$watch`

```
  $scope.$watch('currentPage', function(newPage){
    $scope.watchPage = newPage;
    //or any other code here
  });
```

And here one using the callback:

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(page) {
    $scope.callbackPage = page;
    $scope.watchPage = newPage;
  };
```

used like:

```
<pagination on-select-page="pageChanged(page)" num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage"></pagination>
```

And finally the working plunk showing the 2 approaches:
http://plnkr.co/edit/UgOQo7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I knew it wouldn't be much...irks me that they don't include this part in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  In the "pageChanged" example, what's the purpose of $scope.watchPage = newPage?

Comment: I'm going crazy because I've tried both of these methods before coming  here and neither is working :(

Comment: you might update your answer to include recent changes from `on-select-page` to `ng-change` (see @honkskillet's answer below)

Answer (score 6):

@pkozlowski.opensource answer is correct, except recent versions of bootstrap have changed **on-select-page** to **ng-change**.